# Getting a specified number results when parsing with mechanize

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize-ruby

I am parsing CNN.com to get the top five news storeis with their first paragraph. I have the following code.

```
url = "http://edition.cnn.com/?refresh=1"
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://edition.cnn.com/?refresh=1")
page.search("//div[@id='cnn_maintt2bul']/div/div/ul/li[count(*)=3]/a").map{|a|  page.uri.merge a[:href]}.each do |uri| 
 article = agent.get(uri).parser
 puts article.css(".adtag15090+ p").text
 puts "\n"
end
```

It's not perfect but it works, however, it retrieves all the articles yet I want to retrieve only five articles. Is there a way perhaps using ranges to limit the number of results to five?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to do it is to add an array slice after `search`. Nokogiri returns a NodeSet from a `search`, and [NodeSet supports `[]`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
page.search("//div[@id='cnn_maintt2bul']/div/div/ul/li[count(*)=3]/a")[0, 5]...
```